# In Python, why round(x[,n]) is written instead of round(x,n)?

Tags: python, square-bracket

I have not understood why they write `round(x[,n])` in syntax, but in codes they write `round(10.6987,12)` without square brackets before comma i.e, `round(10.6987[,12])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The square brackets aren't intended to by typed into your code. They just indicate that `n` is an optional parameter.

This style is recommended in the [*Documenting Python*](http://docs.python.org/devguide/documenting.html) guide:

> function
>
> Describes a module-level function. The signature should include the parameters, **enclosing optional parameters in brackets**. Default values can be given if it enhances clarity. For example:

Comment: In python, is square brackets usage same as this normal usage , like <type your name here>.

Comment: Yes, I believe some other languages will use `<` and `>` in a similar way.

Comment: @user2713461 In Python *documentation*, yes. But square brackets to denote optional things in general weren't invented by the Python folks, it's a widely used convention, for example in man pages (`cat [OPTION] [FILE]...`).

Comment: In fact the use of brackets for optionals predates the use for indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets are just a convention used to indicate optional arguments.